# TypeError: $(…).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the above error using the following code inside a ASP.NET MVC

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Prefix: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                    })
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Jquery is definitely loaded, and I have tried using a different variable for $ - any ideas what else might be the problem?

Comment: include jquery-ui also.

Comment: Also added in layout page
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Download these files and reference them for local path.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Please Send me jquery-ui cdn link

Comment: @HassanAbbas might be ordering of js, make sure to load the required libraries before your custom js. Can you show how you added the js files?

Comment: @MairajAhmad download from nuget but same issue occur.

Comment: jquery - `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: How have you included the js in your page ?

Comment: jquery-ui - `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run the application on local and including libraries from server you need to write `http://` or `https://` before the link as when you upload the site on server its not necessary but its required on local

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Or else download them or use from local path.

Comment: i mentioned in my answer if you are calling from live then use http:// or else download them or use from local path.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: open `jsfiddle.net` enter you code and create a working environment there

Comment: @Krishan What is this fiddle for??

Comment: Auto complete exaple.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem??