# TypeError: $(…).autocomplete is not a function with jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the above error using the following code inside ASP.Net MVC

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetCountries",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "",
                results: function (count) {
                    return count + (count > 1 ? ' results' : ' result ') + ' found';
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722506/typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function) but it's not working, it's showing the error.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/7sjrrnmy/. Also note that ASP.Net MVC is not relevant to the problem, so I removed references to it

Comment: Conflicting libraries perhaps?

Comment: I tried it on local machine and works properly, check if you're including another jQuery file somewhere which potentially made conflict.

Comment: okay sir i tired your code @RoryMcCrossan